# Testing bootstrap modal visibility with Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, angular-bootstrap

I can't make Protractor test if a modal is displayed or not.
In my controller on a button click I have the following code:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/modal.html'
     //some extra params
 });
```

where modal.html is a basic html file with containing a div with class 'modal-content'.

When I click the button, this HTML is downloaded and shown but Protractor don't manage to detect the correct behavior:

```
button.click().then(function(){
   browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.className("modal-content"))), 60000);
   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.className("modal-content"))), 60000);
   expect(element(by.className("modal-content")).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
   done();
});
```

Basically although the modal is present and displayed, I have a timeout waiting on the visibility. Any hints?

Comment: Looks like you are opening a modal like a new window because its opening a new url on the current one. Can you try to `getWindowHandle()` and see if there are more than one windows present? If so, then you have to switch to the modal window and then work on it.

Comment: The tricky part is that the same test sometimes fails sometimes has success, it's totally unpredictable.

Comment: Ok. One more thing does your `presenceOf()` succeeds? because visibilityOf checks both isPresent and isDisplayed. Also can you post your complete error too?